# Как проверить пополнение баланса QIWI API, PYTHON?

Tags: python, api, qiwi

Пользователь пополняет мне баланс на киви, после чего нажимает кнопку "Пополнил" и требуется проверить, что он действительно оплатил, а также на какую сумму он пополнил баланс.

В комментариях пользователь указывает свой ид, например он будет 12345. Язык Python. Помогите с реализацией.

Comment: Документация поможет https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#payments_list

Comment: проблема появляется с json ответом, с таким ответом не имею понятия как работать. Не могли бы дать код, который я описываю в теме

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку SimpleQiwi, но сперва вы должны получить токен.
pip install SimpleQIWI

```
from SimpleQIWI import *

token = "ВАШ ТОКЕН"         # https://qiwi.com/api
phone = "ВАШ ТЕЛЕФОН"

api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)

print(api.balance)

# Используйте api.full_balance чтобы получить больше информации о кошельках. 
print(api.payments)
#А так можно получить платежи и посмотреть id человека
```

Примеры можете тут глянуть - https://github.com/Emberium/SimpleQIWI

Comment: До этого момента я уже сделал, но проблема появляется с json ответом, с таким ответом не имею понятия как работать. Не могли бы дать код, который я описываю в теме>